# Can anyone help me fix this error regarding 404 Media_URL styles.css?

Tags: magento-2.1, error

I am seeing this error in the error console 404 (Not Found)  %7B%7BMEDIA_URL%7D%7Dstyles.css. Can anyone offer a solution to fix this?

Answer (score 13):

This error related to Sample Data:

**1. If you use sample data:**

- Check app/etc/config.php: *Magento_ThemeSampleData* should be defined 
  ('Magento_ThemeSampleData' => 1)
- Also check if Sample Data is installed ( main composer.json should require "magento/module-theme-sample-data": "100.1.*" etc )

**2. If you don't use Sample Data:**

You can remove link to this style from admin panel:

For Magento 2.1.5, please navigate: `Content > Configuration`, click <kbd>Edit</kbd> for **Default Store View**, scroll to the `HTML Head` and empty **Scripts and Style Sheets** field, *Save Configuration*.

Comment: MEDIA_URL is not getting replaced with actual url

Answer (score 3):

in Magento 2.3x 
go to content->configuration -> your theme -> htmlhead
in  Scripts and Style Sheets 
remove

done

Comment: After that I've to clear var/cache and var/view_preprocessed

Answer (score 2):

This is (usually) caused when reinstalling a store with sample data with missing modules.

This specific css is required in the theme configuration in the admin area (Content > Visual > Configuration > Theme edit > Header HTML > Stylesheets).

**Removing the css is not always the best solution**, because if you're still using sample data, it can break things in the frontend.

The module responsible for properly replacing `{{MEDIA_URL}}` with the correct value is **Magento_ThemeSampleData**. You can check if you have it and if its enabled by looking in your `app/etc/config.php` (or simply typing `bin/magento module:status`).

If you don't have it, you may want to do:

```
bin/magento sampledata:deploy
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

This will reinstall sample data modules and data, including Magento_TemeSampleData and other sample data modules.

Answer (score 2):

navigate to: **Content** > **Configuration**, click Edit for **Default Store View**, scroll to the **HTML Head** and replace **Scripts and Style Sheets** content with:

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="/pub/media/styles.css" />
```

than **Save Configuration**.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error while using the Sample Data.  I fixed it with:

```
bin/magento sampledata:reset
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, {{MEDIA_URL}} is being used by Magento_ThemeSampleData only,

You can use this without installing Magento_ThemeSampleData, need to create a plugin

**Ricky/ThemeSetup/etc/module.xml**

```
<module name="Ricky_ThemeSetup" >
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
        <module name="Magento_Store"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

**Ricky/ThemeSetup/etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config">
    <plugin name="headIncludes" type="Ricky\ThemeSetup\Plugin\View\Page\Config" />
</type>
```

**Ricky/ThemeSetup/Plugin/View/Page/Config.php**

```
namespace Ricky\ThemeSetup\Plugin\View\Page;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config as PageConfig;

class Config
{
/**
 * Url configuration
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
 */
protected $baseUrl;

/**
 * @param UrlInterface $baseUrl
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $baseUrl
) {
    $this->baseUrl = $baseUrl;
}

/**
 * @param PageConfig $subject
 * @param string $result
 * @return string
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function afterGetIncludes(PageConfig $subject, $result)
{
    $pattern = '{{MEDIA_URL}}';
    if (strpos($result, $pattern) !== false) {
        $url = $this->baseUrl->getBaseUrl(['_type' => \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA]);
        $result = str_replace($pattern, $url, $result);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

}

I hope this will help.